# How large a class of rings are the noetherian domains that have finite character?

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian

A commutative ring $R$ has finite character if every nonzero element of $R$ is contained in at most finitely many maximal ideals. I am interested in the particular case in which $R$ is a Noetherian domain. I don't know a lot about this case other than that Dedekind domains have finite character, as well as $1$-dimensional Noetherian domains. What I am hoping is that this class of rings (Noetherian domains of finite character) is fairly robust. If someone could supply an example or two to show what scope this class has, I would be grateful.

EDIT: This question arises from an expository paper I have been preparing. I have generalized arguments of Rotman and Enochs to construct co-Hopfian modules (over Noetherian rings of finite character) of uncountable cardinality that arise as direct products. Following an argument of user "moonlight" on this site, I have shown that the injective envelope of these modules is not co-Hopfian if the ring is also an integral domain (with certain cardinality requirements on its maximal spectrum) . What I am hoping, and have been unable to determine or find in the literature, is that my result is valid for more than $1$-dimensional Noetherian domains, hence my request for assistance.

EDIT 2:  After poring over my copy of Kaplansky's *Commutative Rings,* I was wondering if there may be a connection to Krull domains.

Comment: This is probably too late to be useful to you, but anyways: there exist non-semilocal Noetherian domains of finite character of any dimension (including infinity). Indeed, Nagata's example of an infinite-dimensional Noetherian ring is of finite character (which is usually a stepping stone in showing that it is Noetherian), and can be easily modified to give examples in any finite dimension $\ge 2$.

Comment: @math54321 - That's good to know (Nagata's example has finite character). I believe I ran across the modification in an article by Bruce Olberding (Characterization and constructions of h-local domains, in Contributions to Module Theory (deGruyter) pp1-21). You have been very helpful. Thank you.